# PHP cant use function var outside of function even though set to global

Tags: php

This wont echo the vars

```
<?php
function myfunc(){
    function gettime(){
        $date = date('d-m-y h:i:s');
        global $date;
    }
    function getURL(){
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        global $url;
    }
    function getrequest(){
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        $request = explode("/", substr(@$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1));
        
        switch ($method) {
          case 'PUT': 
            $requestmethod = 'GET';
            break;
          case 'POST':
            $requestmethod = 'POST';
            break;
          case 'GET': 
            $requestmethod = 'GET';
            break;
          default:
          $requestmethod = 'unkown';
            break;
        }
        global $requestmethod;
    }
}
myfunc();
echo $requestmethod.$url.$date;
```

How can I get `$date` (and all others) to `echo` their values?

I set them to `Global`, and even if I put `echo` inside of the function, it still didn't work.

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve? What have you tried so far to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Solved Already From everyone below (fixed both issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `global` needs to be first, otherwise it overwrites when called.

For example:

```
function gettime(){
    global $date;
    $date = date('d-m-y h:i:s');
}
```

compare https://3v4l.org/M8P7T to https://3v4l.org/irRHf

As noted on the other answer though you also still need to call the functions.

Answer (score 0):

you are `declaring` the functions, but you are not `calling` them.

Try this:

```
function gettime(){
    $date = date('d-m-y h:i:s');
    global $date;
}
function getURL(){
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    global $url;
}
function getrequest(){
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $request = explode("/", substr(@$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1));
    
    switch ($method) {
      case 'PUT': 
        $requestmethod = 'GET';
        break;
      case 'POST':
        $requestmethod = 'POST';
        break;
      case 'GET': 
        $requestmethod = 'GET';
        break;
      default:
      $requestmethod = 'unkown';
        break;
    }
    global $requestmethod;
}

function myfunc(){
    gettime(); // You invoke the function gettime, so it get executed
    getURL(); // You invoke the function getURL, so it get executed
    getrequest(); // You invoke the function getrequest, so it get executed
}

myfunc();
echo $requestmethod.$url.$date;
```

Comment: When i run it, i still get nothing, do i have another issue with my code?

Comment: what i mean by nothing echo returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like this: 
replace "global" with "return".

```
function gettime(){
    $date = date('d-m-y h:i:s');
    return $date;
}
```

instead of using `myfunc();` Initiate myFunc() and store it inside a variable as below.

```
$myFunc = myfunc();
```

Now you can call all variables and methods inside it
example :

```
echo $myFunc.gettime();
```

Comment: Tested and it works
https://phpsandbox.io/n/eeo5u